# R: sort a matrix so that high values ​lie along the main diagonal and get smaller outwards

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, matrix, data.table

I have a squared matrix in a data frame and need to swap rows and columns so that the highes values are on the main diagonale and get smaller outwards. I have trouble getting the correct function getRK() which should tell me if a swap would change the matrix a step closer to my goal.
Also, does a specific name for such a matrix exist?

**visualization of my goal:** 
dark green: highest values 
medium green: medium values 
bright green: lowest values
[image: visualization of my goal]

I have tried the following:

```
dataframe <- data.table(matrix(rpois(64,8),ncol=8))
for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
  colnames(dataframe)[i] <- paste0("M",i)
  rownames(dataframe)[i] <- paste0("M",i)
}

getRK <- function(dataframe,row_arg,column_arg){
  row <- min(c(row_arg,column_arg))
  column <- max(c(row_arg,column_arg))

  SO <- sum(dataframe[row,(row+1):column])
  if((column-row)>1){
    SO <- SO+sum(dataframe[((row+1):(column-1)), ..column])
  }
  SU <- sum(dataframe[column,row:(column-1)])
  if((column-row>1)){
    SU <- SU+sum(dataframe[(row+1):(column-1), ..row])
  }
  #print(paste0("SO=",SO))
  #print(paste0("SU=",SU))
  return (SU-SO)
}

k <- 1
while (TRUE){
  print(paste0("rotation=",k))
  compare <- dataframe
  for(swap1 in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
    for(swap2 in 1:nrow(dataframe)){
      #no need to swap same columns/rows
      if(swap1 == swap2){next}
      RK_start_swap <- getRK(dataframe,swap1,swap2)
      #swap row
      tmp <- dataframe[swap1,]
      dataframe[swap1,] <- dataframe [swap2,]
      dataframe[swap2,] <- tmp
      
      #swap column
      tmp <- dataframe[, ..swap1]
      dataframe[, swap1] <- c(dataframe [, ..swap2])
      dataframe[, swap2] <- tmp
      
      RK_end_swap <- getRK(dataframe,swap1,swap2)
      if(RK_end_swap > RK_start_swap){
        #swap back column
        tmp <- dataframe[swap2,]
        dataframe[swap2,] <- dataframe [swap1,]
        dataframe[swap1,] <- tmp
        
        #swap back row
        tmp <- dataframe[, ..swap2]
        dataframe[,  swap2] <- c(dataframe [, ..swap1])
        dataframe[,  swap1] <- tmp
      }else{
        print("swapped because new version corresponds better to the goal")
      }
    }
  }
  # TRUE if no changes done (goal reached)
  if (any((dataframe == compare)==TRUE)){
    print("done!")
     break;
  }
  k <- k+1
}
```

Comment: If there is a single highest value, does it go to top left or bottom right of the matrix? After filling in the diagonal do you start above the diagonal or below?

Comment: @sindri_baldur in my case the single highest values should go to the top left. Because I need to swap whole rows/columns there will be situations where its more important to have higher values along the diagonal than having the highest on the top left. After filling the diagonal I start above it with the next values.

Comment: can you provide exact data maybe for matrix colors?